# Defining host as variable in Ansible hosts file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a rather simple `hosts` file

```
[clients]
qas0062
[dbs_server]
qas0063
```

For the users of the project we don't want them to modify `hosts` file but rather we have a separate `user.config.yml` file that contain various user-configurable parameters. There we have entry such as

```
dbs_server: qas0065
```

So the question is: is it possible to use a variable in the `hosts` file that would use a value defined in `user.config.yml`? And what would be the format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you can't templatize the actual host key entry in the inventory, but you can templatize the value of its `ansible_host` connection var to achieve roughly the same effect, eg:

```
[clients]
clienthost ansible_host="{{ clienthost_var }}"
[dbs_server]
dbsserver ansible_host="{{ dbsserver_var }}"
```

then set the value of those vars from external vars before the play starts executing (eg, with the `vars_files` directive or -e).

Comment: Thanks for your solution, Matt. I will try it today.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do the same thing. We can simply refer to values in the hosts (inventory) file by using the following syntax in our playbook

`host={{ groups['dbs_server'][0] }}`

This works well when you have one entry in the group (db_server in this specific case)