# Define ansible-host variable for host using a pattern

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Given the following:

```
all:
  ...
  children:
     node[01-05]:
```

How do I apply `ansible-host` with (unsurprisingly) differing values to each of `node` ?

How do I do it if the `ansible-host` value follows a similar pattern? Would this be valid?

```
  node[01-05]:
    ansible-host: servers.node[01-05].example.com
```

What if the values for `ansible-host` would be completely different?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665682/defining-host-as-variable-in-ansible-hosts-file) seems to do some substituting from a variable file, but I am not sure if this can be applied to my hosts file and solves my issue.

Answer (score 3):

- Your example above does not declare *hosts* but a **group**.
- If you want to declare a range of hosts, the syntax is `prefix[start:end]suffix`. In your case:

```yaml
all:
  children:
    my_nodes:
      hosts:
        "node[01:05]":
```

The quotes around the range are needed to let yaml know where the identifier ends

*** Edit *** and to save you the hassle of setting the ansible host for each of your nodes, you can declare them directly with their proper names:

```yaml
all:
  children:
    my_nodes:
      hosts:
        "servers.node[01:05].example.com":
```

If you still really need to have an inventory_hostname different from ansible_host, you can set a var based on the inventory for the whole group

```yaml
all:
  children:
    my_nodes:
      vars:
        ansible_host: "servers.{{ inventory_hostname }}.example.com"
      hosts:
        "node[01:05]":
```

- It is not possible to list individual host vars for a range. If you want to keep those vars in the inventory, you will have to re-list each individual host in the range (e.g in the 'all' group directly) and put the vars there. (hence loosing the benefit of using a range in first place). If you have a lot of hosts/groups, listing vars directly in the inventory will quickly become a nightmare (and is not recommended by the documentaion). You should rely on the `host_vars/group_vars` directory and have a `hostname.yml/groupname.yml` file for each needed server/group. Have a look at the doc for more info on this subject: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data